# Is it possible to show more preview subtext lines in Alfred search

Tags: dictionary, alfred

When I search for something in Alfred, like in the dictionary result in the image below, it only shows one line of the subtext.

Is it possible to show more lines? Especially for word definitions, I would prefer to see more info right in Alfred instead of having to open the entire dictionary app.

[image: alfred search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't. However, there is a [workflow](https://github.com/mr-pennyworth/alfred-better-dictionaries) which makes dictionary browsing with Alfred better.

[image: example]